# Linux - change default location of directories like Downloads, Documents, Pictures

Tags: linux, home-directory

I know there is a **command** (but I forgot it) that changes the **default location** of following directories:

- Documents
- Music
- Pictures
- Public
- Templates
- Videos
- ...

I do **not** want to change the *home directory*, the command is not `usermod`.

---

I also tried googling it, but couldn't find anything on that... But I am 100% sure that there is this command, because I have used it before and now after my new Arch installation I want to have the same structure as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do it.

**1.** The one you seem to want, as suggested in a comment by Destroy666, is

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set NAME PATH
```

wherein NAME is one of `DESKTOP`, `DOWNLOAD`, `TEMPLATES`, `PUBLICSHARE`, `DOCUMENTS`, `MUSIC`, `PICTURES`, or `VIDEOS`, and PATH is the absolute path that you want for the directory (which can but need not contain `$HOME` to be expanded by the shell, e.g. `$HOME/Photos` = `/home/user/Photos` if you'd like your photos to be there instead of the default `$HOME/Pictures` = `/home/user/Pictures`).

Note that this will only change the directories for the user invoking the command.

**2.** The second way to do it is to rewrite the per-user configuration file, which defaults to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and has the syntax

```
NAME="PATH"
```

wherein NAME and PATH have the same form as before. `$HOME` will be expanded in this file just as it would be in the shell, so that's still OK.

This only applies to the specific user. `xdg-user-dirs-update --set` just modifies this file; that's why the command also only works per-user.

**3.** The third way to do it is to modify the system-wide configuration file, which by default is in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`. This file has a slightly different syntax

```
NAME=PATH
```

wherein PATH is by assumption relative to the user's home directory.

This approach will change the defaults for all users on the system, but users' personal configuration files (`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`) will override it.

Note that I'm having some trouble myself with settings in this global configuration file being respected, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. Actually even more, I learned a couple of new things. Perfect answer :) I can't upvote yet, but as soon as I can I am gonna upvote your answer^^

Answer (score 0):

### Change specific dir(s)

I'm pretty sure you're looking for [XDG directory commands](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_user_directories). For example, to change music dir, you can run:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set MUSIC "/some/dir/music"
```

Default dir values are:

- `DESKTOP`
- `DOCUMENTS`
- `DOWNLOAD`
- `MUSIC`
- `PICTURES`
- `PUBLICSHARE`
- `TEMPLATES`
- `VIDEOS`

**Note**: uppercase letters are important, it's case sensitive.

You can also set your own directories if you desire.

### Change all dirs

You can also run:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

To create/reload `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs`) file with all the definitions, which you can also edit directly with any text editor.